# Enable a button in a form if a condition is met inside a User control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform, Inside a added a save button (named "btnsave") but is disabled.

I also added a user control with a datagridview and other textbox and labels.

I want to enable the save button in the main form when something change inside the user control.

I have the event to detect changes in the dgv and textboxes
And I used this to enable the save button:

```
var form = this.parent as Form;
form.Controls["btnsave"].Enabled= true;
```

I don't get any error but the save button is never enable. In the inspector I see The button has a property `canenableme=false`

How can I archive this?

Comment: Not sure about canenable.  Can’t say I’ve ever noticed.  I think you problem might be this.parent will refer to the parent form of your form.  You should be able simplify this by just doing btnsave.enabled=true

Comment: You can try calling DoEvents().  Also set a break point and make sure the code is being called.

Comment: Are you sure that your code enabling the button is executed?

Comment: Yes I'm sure the code is enabling the button and that the rigth button is found using the code above... I will try to put more code here so you can understand better